# How to prove that $M \cong \mathrm{ker}(f) \oplus A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $A$-module, $A$ commutative ring.

$ f : M \to A$ is a surjective morphism, then prove that $$M \cong ker(f) \oplus A$$

Any hint ?

Comment: Fyi, it's always a good idea to have text in the title so that people who want to open questions in a new tab/window can.  If the title is only text then the MathJax context menu prevents people from getting to their normal right click menu.

Comment: Do you know what a splitting short exact sequence is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$0\to \mathrm{ker \ f} \to M \to A \to 0$ is exact and $A$ is free, hence this is a split short exact sequence.

Answer (score 3):

There exist a morphism $g:A\to M$ such that $f\circ g = Id_A$.